# How to reload content Placeholder

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I use MasterPage in myapp.Masterpage contain contentPlaceHolder and treeVeiw in left side.
I want after click on node,reload contentPlaceHolder but i  do not want use Updatepanel.
Is there a way to use jquery?

```
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
  <obout:Tree ID="Tree1" runat="server" Width="200px">
</obout:Tree>
</div>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What is it that will appear in the ContentPlaceHolder? Are you loading other controls into it, or just simple HTML?

Comment: there are more ascx in my project and Base on selected node, must load specific ascx in contentplaceholder

Comment: What are your reasons for not wanting to use an UpdatePanel? I think you'd need to do a full postback of the page to load an ascx into the ContentPlaceHolder. An UpdatePanel would do this, whilst appearing to only update that panel.